# Is there any size limit in arraylist used in "where in" in java named query?

Tags: java, named-query

Is there any size limit in arraylist used in "where in" in java named query?

Comment: I have no idea what your title is even asking. "as title" is a VERY poor body to a question. Please update your question to make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Oracle 10g you can you use 1000.  I think this is entirely database-specific as opposed to Java or JDBC specific.